# How to properly handled httpClient?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, httpclient

This is my current code,

*service.ts*

```
export class ApiServiceFunction {
    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
    ) { }

    // in app.ts for test connection
    testConnection() {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/connection`)
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                console.log('Handling error locally and rethrowing it...', err);
                return throwError(err);
            })
        );
    }
}
```

*component.ts*

```
  private testConnection() {
    this.ApiServiceFunction.testConnection()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('data ', data)
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error ',error)

      },
    );
  }
```

Error shows in console

> Handling error locally and rethrowing it... Unknown Error

> app.component.ts:190 error  Unknown Error

> zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://172.16.0.115:8080/connection net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

I want to get the error test
**"ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED"**

Comment: Check this Tutorial: https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thank you for sharing. I took a look on the example but its not solving my problem. The problem is, I cannot get the exact error when there is an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can handle it manually.

You should add the method that gives us user status

then in `catchError` block handle behavior

```
    get isOnline() {
        return navigator.onLine;
    }

    testConnection() {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/connection`)
            .pipe(catchError(e => {
                if (!this.isOnline) {
                    return throwError('ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED')
                }
                return throwError(e)
            })
    }
```

Comment: It was a nice tips using navigator.online. But, how to check if
- net::ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED
- net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: it is another question

Comment: @saifuladham in your case we can implement OfflineInterceptor that will be track changes. See link https://netbasal.com/manage-http-downtime-with-angular-rxjs-and-http-interceptors-3e520b292ece

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply extract the error from the error string, an example of how this can be done using regexp is as per below

```js
const err = "zone-evergreen.js:2845 GET http://172.16.0.115:8080/connection net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED unknown err";

const extractErr = err.match(/net\:\:([A-Z|_]+)/gm)[0].split('::')[1]

console.log(extractErr)
```